# Heuristic Answers to Self-derived Questions

Tags: discussion

So I put in my [first answer that I felt uncomfortable about](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/25913/balanced-vs-maximized-codon-optimization/25978#25978), and it was to my question.  I'm uncomfortable about it for a lot of reasons, mostly in that I don't think that it fully addresses the question asked, but I'm now rather certain the literature doesn't have an awnser to the question asked.

Are heuristic answers, especially to your own questions, acceptable here?  I realize that's how the majority of answers are reached on a site like SO, but they feel less appropriate here.  Would such answers be better if they included actual data (ie a Western image)?  I run into the problem in that much of what I'm doing is covered in intellectual property issues, and I wouldn't be able to give a detailed account of what was in each lane (protein #1 instead ENV for example).

I'm happy to remove the answer.  I didn't find something that seemed to address this question exactly so I thought I would put up and then ask here.

Edit:
I should point out that when the question is on a technical topic, like [buffer prep](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9266/high-current-speed-transfer-buffer-recipe), it doesn't bother me to do this.  It's more when it's a question of nature, like codon bias, that I am more concerned.